# Block multiple select scrolling to top when selection changes

Tags: javascript, select, scroll, block

How can I disable scrolling to top of selected items when I select one option? It's simple multiple select with js that can be used with multiple select without clrt+C, code down.

```
window.onmousedown = function (e) {

    var el = e.target;

    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // toggle selection
        if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) 
            el.removeAttribute('selected');
        else 
            el.setAttribute('selected', '');

        // hack to correct buggy behavior
        var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previous scrollTop position and reapply it, like so:

```
window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var el = e.target;

    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // save scroll state
        var yeOldeScroll = el.scrollTop;

        // toggle selection
        if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) {
            el.removeAttribute('selected');
        } else {
            el.setAttribute('selected', '');
        }

        // re-apply scroll state
        el.scrollTop = yeOldeScroll;

        // hack to correct buggy behavior
        var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
    }
}
```